# Arrows in API strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So this is probably as straightforward a question as can be. I'm using an API in my React project and it returns strings in many cases. However, I noticed that the longer texts have strange arrows in them (image below) and I have no idea what they are, so I can't even format the text properly. Does anyone know what this is about? Thanks!

[image: Just to be clear, I drew the blue square myself, it's not part of the arrow]

Comment: What does the code look like that shows the API result? What does the API itself return?

Comment: I'll show what it returns pertaining to the example in the image. "When several of these POKéMON gather, theirelectricity could build and cause lightning storms." As you can see, it looks as if there's nothing there.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle for this? just attempt to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'll fix one up

Comment: It's mostly because of white spaces and line breaks. you can use `trim()` on every word to fix that

Comment: @ShawnVn what does that mean exactly? And how could I go about removing it from the string?

Comment: @VicHofs I guess the arrow in your string stands for some kind of white spaces or line breaks before a word. it seems that your string does not have any white spaces in it, and all of the white spaces have been removed; the white spaces that didn't removed have replaced with arrows. Do you do any thing on the string after you've fetched it from API or the API returns the string like this ?

Comment: @ShawnVn No, I just get the string like this

Comment: example at https://codesandbox.io/s/eggsmaple-0np3j (I'm more used to codesandbox than fiddle but it won't really make a difference)

Comment: @VicHofs I've fix it checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution

It's because there is a weird and non-standard character instead of white space in your string.

The code below will fix your problem :)

```
const fixedString = yourString.replace(String.fromCharCode(12)," ")
```